# Remove object from array - object is returned instead of array

Tags: php, arrays

I'm looping through an array of `$students` and removing those that are already in the `$enrolled` array.

```
$i=0;
foreach($students as $student)
{
    foreach($enrolled as $enrollment)
    {
        if ($enrollment->id == $student->id)
        {
            unset($students[$i]);
        }
    }
    $i++;
}

return Response::json(array(
    'available' => $students
));
```

That leaves me with the following output:

```
"available": {
    "2": {
        "id": "4"
        "user_id": "4",
        "teacher_id": null,
        "parent_id": "4",
        "active": "1"
    }
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that `available` is an *array*, holding that one student. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand what is the problem with the output. Were you expecting more than one student in the *available* array?

Comment: @VitorLima The output is an object with a key, not an array.

Comment: Do yo realize that foreach and unset on the same element is quite bad? it cannot be done this way

Comment: Remove `Response::json()` from the return?

Comment: I think that *json()* always output a *hash* like this, because it is trying to transform your php array in a string. You can verify it by just calling *Response::json(array('a', 'b', 'c'))*...

Comment: To get a javascript array, you probably need to re-index it before you encode it as json: `$students = array_values($students);`

Comment: The problem is that it is starting in the index 2? If yes, so, @jeroen's comment will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($students); $i++)
{
    $student = $students[$i];
    foreach($enrolled as $enrollment)
    {
        if ($enrollment->id == $student->id)
        {
            unset($students[$i]);
        }
    }
}

return Response::json(array(
    'available' => array_values($students)
));
```

don't use `foreach` and `unset` on the same element, better would be `for`, because `unset` causes some problems to `foreach` if you think about it how `foreach` works (iterators, keys, whatever)

Comment: That still gives the same format for the output - i.e. and object with key being the index of the `$students` array.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript arrays are zero-indexed so you cannot have an array with one element and an index that is not zero.

To get that from your php array, you need to re-index it before you encode it:

```
// re-index the array
$students = array_values($students);

return Response::json(array(
    'available' => $students
));
```

See a [simple example here](http://codepad.viper-7.com/ew0Pui).